# Spotlight cone has a black frame in all views

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I'm using Blender 2.8, using the Eevee render.  I have added a spotlight.  The cone and the 'light bulb' show as black lines in any view, it's a bit like a wireframe.  Any idea how to get rid of these lines?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender's StackExchange! The spotlight shows the light cone by default. Do you want to hide it or are you referring to something else? It may help if you add a screenshot and mark what particular lines you mean.

Comment: I want the light cone to show, but I don't want the black outline of the cone, there is also a black line down the middle of the cone.  Also the 'light bulb' is black.  Sorry I'm new on here and don't know how to add a screenshot.

Comment: You can add an image to your question by clicking *edit* underneath it and then on the little image icon next to the curly braces. Do you mean the black lines that are shown in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwTal.jpg ?

Comment: Thank you for the adding image instructions.  Yes those are the black lines, as shown in your image.

Comment: I don't know if you can get rid, but you can select the light in the viewport and you can scale down the cone with S, it won't affect its effect on the scene

Comment: These lines are just to indicate the light's position, direction and light cone. They won't appear in the actual rendered image, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added the screenshot.  I've tried to find a setting to make the black lines go away, but I can't find anything.  Even in render view, they're still there?

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of all overlays in preview render:
[image]

1. Disable "show cone" in the light settings
   [image: cone diabled]
2. Disable "show overlays" in 3D View
   [image: overlays disabled]
3. Disable "show Gizmo" also in 3D View
   [image: gizmos disabled]

Comment: Ahh OK, I thought the cone was a renderable function in itself!!  Thank you